# redirect url with query string to ca certain page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have URLs which look like this: https://domain.de/immobilien?bis-kaltmiete&info-message=test&vermarktungsart=miete&von-kaltmiete&callback=confirm_searchagent&confirm=1aa46e80c4d57ef40a6ddab59cf5aebd#flash-message

Now i want to redirect URLs with the certain query "callback=confirm_searchagent". I tryed to do this via .htaccess and used the following code

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^callback=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /immobilien/ [R=301,L]
```

The code did not change anything, no redirection, no errors.

i hope somebody can help me with this?

Comment: So, _any_ URL that contains the URL parameter `callback=confirm_searchagent` should be redirected to `/immobilien/` exactly (removing the query string)?

Comment: yes, exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} callback=(.*)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /immobilien/? [R=301,L]
```

I removed the `^` from your condition regex as it was looking for a query string that starts with this spacific key. Also I added a `?` at the end of the rule to remove query strings from the new redirected URL. You can remove this `?` if you want query string appended.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes we can , but then this won't match the requested URL. The URL has multiple query parameters. OP wants the redirection to happen only when the specific query key value is present in their URL. I think the pattern should be replaced with `callback=confirm_searchagent`  to make the match more specific and strict. I will update my answer after receiving any feedback from the poster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Unfortunately, nothing happens with this code either.

Comment: here is my full rewrite:

     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} callback=(.*)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /immobilien/? [R=301,L]
       </IfModule>

Comment: "but then this won't match the requested URL." - Yes it will. It will be successful, although doesn't match anything - but it doesn't need to actually match anything in the example as posted. `^` is simply more efficient than `^(.*)$` here. (Unless they are wanting to redirect to the same URL-path - a reason for the capturing subgroup - but that is not mentioned in the question.) @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @tom84 You've put the rule in the wrong place, this needs to go _before_ the rewrite (nearer the top of the file). That looks like the WordPress code block, in which case, this rule should go before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.